How to enumerate files on a specific folder using Windows shell apis?
Im trying to enumerate all files on a given path and also get their properties.
On my implementation below, i dont understand whats happening, it looks like it somehow is using the computer desktop path instead of the path on folderPath
at hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &displayName); it shows:
C:\Users\Lilo\Desktop\file.txt instead of: C:\Users\Lilo\Documents\file.txt
file.txt is on the documents folder not on the desktop
and consequently both SHGetPropertyStoreFromIDList and SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName fails with
HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) : The system cannot find the file specified.
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <atlcomcli.h>

inline void enumFiles(const std::wstring& folderPath)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    HRESULT hr;
    CComPtr<IShellItem>   pFolderItem = NULL;
    CComPtr<IShellFolder> pFolder     = NULL;

    hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(folderPath.c_str(), NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFolderItem));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "SHCreateItemFromParsingName failed with HRESULT:" << hr;
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }
    
    hr = pFolderItem->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_SFObject, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFolder));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "BindToHandler failed with HRESULT:" << hr;
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }
  
    CComPtr<IEnumIDList> pEnum = NULL;
    hr = pFolder->EnumObjects(NULL, SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, &pEnum);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "EnumObjects failed with HRESULT:" << hr;
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }

    ITEMIDLIST* pidl = NULL;
    ULONG fetched;

    while (pEnum->Next(1, &pidl, &fetched) == S_OK)
    {
        CComPtr<IShellItem> pItem;
        hr = SHCreateItemFromIDList(pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pItem));
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            std::cout << "SHCreateItemFromIDList failed with HRESULT:" << hr;
            CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
            continue;
        }

        LPWSTR displayName;
        hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &displayName);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            CoTaskMemFree(displayName);

        CComPtr<IPropertyStore> pPropertyStore;
        GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS flags = GPS_DEFAULT;
        hr = SHGetPropertyStoreFromIDList(pidl, flags, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropertyStore));
        //hr = SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(displayName, NULL, GPS_DEFAULT, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropertyStore));
        CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            std::cout << "SHGetPropertyStoreFromIDList failed with HRESULT:" << hr;
            continue;
        }
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    enumFiles(L"C:\\Users\\Lilo\\Documents");
}


Why don't you use the standard std::filesystem::directory_iterator (or std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator) ?

Im also reading the file properties.

I understand. std::filesystem does provide some of the properties, but not all.

You can keep on using IShellItem and friends (IEnumShellItems) all along, IShellFolder is the underlying folder interface that's not easy to use, something like this (error-checks ommited):
void enumFiles(const std::wstring& folderPath)
{
    CComPtr<IShellItem> folder;
    SHCreateItemFromParsingName(folderPath.c_str(), nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&folder));

    // create a bind context to define what we want to enumerate
    CComPtr<IPropertyBag> bag;
    PSCreateMemoryPropertyStore(IID_PPV_ARGS(&bag));

    CComPtr<IBindCtx> ctx;
    CreateBindCtx(0, &ctx);
    ctx->RegisterObjectParam((LPOLESTR)STR_PROPERTYBAG_PARAM, bag);
    auto flags = CComVariant(SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS);
    bag->Write(STR_ENUM_ITEMS_FLAGS, &flags);

    CComPtr<IEnumShellItems> items;
    folder->BindToHandler(ctx, BHID_EnumItems, IID_PPV_ARGS(&items));

    do
    {
        CComPtr<IShellItem> item;
        if (items->Next(1, &item, nullptr) != S_OK)
            break;

        CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> displayName;
        item->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &displayName);

        std::wcout << displayName.m_pData << std::endl;

        CComPtr<IPropertyStore> store;
        if (FAILED(item->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_PropertyStore, IID_PPV_ARGS(&store))))
        {
          CComPtr<IPropertyStoreFactory> factory;
          item->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_PropertyStore, IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory));

          factory->GetPropertyStore(GPS_BESTEFFORT, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&store));
        }

        // etc.

    } while (true);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    {
        enumFiles(L"C:\\Users\\Lilo\\Documents");
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}

See here for more on the possible bind contexts.
PS 1: don't call CoInitalize in a library code, just call it once per process/thread.
PS 2: ATL has CComHeapPtr for smart memory pointer.

Even specifying auto flags = CComVariant(SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_CHECKING_FOR_CHILDREN); its not iterating over the folders

@lillo - SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_CHECKING_FOR_CHILDREN does iterate on folders (not on files). SHCONTF_CHECKING_FOR_CHILDREN is more a hint for the IShellFolder implementer but shouldn't change the output

Thank you helped a lot! do you know where is the key of System.Software.ProductVersion? it should be something like PKEY_ProductVersion but its missing on the microsoft header propkey.h,  i figured out its GUID {fmtid={0CEF7D53-FA64-11D1-A203-0000F81FEDEE} pid=8 } but its also not on the propkey.h header

Some PROPERTYKEYs are  not super documented, AFAIK, this one, named PKEY_Software_ProductVersion, is not defined in a .h, only in uuid.lib https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=0cef7d53-fa64-11d1-a203-0000f81fedee Note you can always get a PROPERTYKEY from a canonical name such as "System.Software.ProductVersion" using PSGetPropertyKeyFromName https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-psgetpropertykeyfromname

The problem with your code is that the IEnumIDList you are getting from pFolder->EnumObjects() gives you child PIDLs that are relative to the IShellFolder being enumerated, but you are then treating them as-if they were absolute PIDLs instead, which they are not.
Per the IEnumIDList::Next() documentation:

HRESULT Next(
  [in]  ULONG         celt,
  [out] PITEMID_CHILD *rgelt, // <-- !!!!
  [out] ULONG         *pceltFetched
);

...
The ITEMIDLIST structures returned in the array are relative to the IShellFolder being enumerated.

And per the SHCreateItemFromIDList() documentation:

SHSTDAPI SHCreateItemFromIDList(
  [in]  PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl, // <-- !!!
  [in]  REFIID            riid,
  [out] void              **ppv
);


And the SHGetPropertyStoreFromIDList() documentation:

SHSTDAPI SHGetPropertyStoreFromIDList(
  [in]  PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE     pidl, // <--!!!
  [in]  GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS flags,
  [in]  REFIID                riid,
  [out] void                  **ppv
);


So, when you pass a relative PIDL to SHCreateItemFromIDList() and SHGetPropertyStoreFromIDList(), it gets mis-interpreted as being relative to the top-level Desktop namespace:
ITEMIDLIST Strict Types:

As of Windows Vista, several forms of ITEMIDLIST are available as data types. The three main types are:

IDLIST_ABSOLUTE: Fully qualified ITEMIDLIST relative to the root of the namespace. It may be multi-level.
IDLIST_RELATIVE: ITEMIDLIST relative to a parent folder. It may be multi-level.
ITEMID_CHILD: Single-level ITEMIDLIST relative to a parent folder. It contains exactly one SHITEMID structure.


That is why pItem->GetDisplayName() is giving you file paths underneath your Desktop folder, and why SHGetPropertyStoreFromIDList() fails to get an IPropertyStore for a non-existing file.
If you compile your code with STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS defined, the compiler should catch this mismatch and fail.
That being said, to get an IShellItem for a child of an IShellFolder, you can use SHCreateShellItem() or SHCreateItemWithParent(), eg:
CComPtr<IShellItem> pItem;
hr = SHCreateShellItem(NULL, pFolder, pidl, &pItem);

CComPtr<IShellItem> pItem;
hr = SHCreateItemWithParent(NULL, pFolder, pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pItem));

And to get an IPropertyStore for an IShellItem, you can use IShellItem::BindToHandler(), eg:
CComPtr<IPropertyStore> pPropertyStore;
hr = pItem->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_PropertyStore, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropertyStore));

Alternatively, you can query the IShellItem for IShellItem2 and then use IShellItem2::GetPropertyStore(), eg:
CComQIPtr<IShellItem2> pItem2(pItem);
CComPtr<IPropertyStore> pPropertyStore;
hr = pItem2->GetPropertyStore(GPS_DEFAULT, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropertyStore));


Do you know why some files when you call BindToHandle hr = pItem->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_PropertyStore, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropertyStore)); it always fail with HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND) : The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.? for example, i was enumerating the modules loaded on my process and getting their properties, this file always fails with this error: C:\\Windows\\System32\\umpdc.dll

@Lillo no, I do not.

@Lillo - In this case, the error is caused by the files that have no VERSIONINFO Win32 resource. You can use GPS_BESTEFFORT as a flag to avoid this error.

@SimonMourier taking your answer as base instead of hr = bag->Write(STR_ENUM_ITEMS_FLAGS, &flags); which is used on the BindToHandler for BHID_EnumItems, how would it be on the case of BHID_PropertyStore?

I've updated my answer, it's better to get the pstore factory

@SimonMourier why not use IShellItem2::GetPropertyStore() instead of IPropertyStoreFactory? You can pass GPS_BESTEFFORT to it

@RemyLebeau - sure, that's equivalent, but in my code I just wasn't using IShellItem2
